# Will multiple AWS Lambdas making request to some HTTP(s) resource be detected as throttling?

Tags: http, aws-lambda, throttling

Suppose I have multiple AWS Lambdas making a request to some HTTP API, is there any documentation how these requests will be seen on the API side in terms of throttling. Will they be treated as requests coming from different hosts or sometimes (or always) the same one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assume no 2 runs of the same Lambda function will even run on the same machine. AWS might reuse the same instance to run your function, but that's to save the time spent downloading the code on every function call.

You can here from the AWS Lambda FAQ page found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/), the following:

> **Q: Will AWS Lambda reuse function instances?**
>
> To improve performance, AWS Lambda may choose to retain an instance of
>   your function and reuse it to serve a subsequent request, rather than
>   creating a new copy. To learn more about how Lambda reuses function
>   instances, visit our documentation. Your code should not assume that
>   this will always happen.
>
> **Q: Why must AWS Lambda functions be stateless?**
>
> Keeping functions stateless enables AWS Lambda to rapidly launch as
>   many copies of the function as needed to scale to the rate of incoming
>   events. While AWS Lambda’s programming model is stateless, your code
>   can access stateful data by calling other web services, such as Amazon
>   S3 or Amazon DynamoDB.

Also, to understand more take a look at [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/) interesting blog post (back from 2014)

Comment: So, what about when I create function and click `test` in AWS console? Should it be the same? Cause I tried. Clicking consistently or waiting for a while still renders the same IP address in remove API logs. Or it's just a special case?

Comment: That's just a special case. From my understanding of your new comments, you want the up to change as much as possible to avoid throttling. If you really wanna see the power of AWS Lambda, write a script that would make a 100 request (will cost you pennies) and you'll see the function running in parallel with multiple ips.

Comment: @IvanYouroff how often do you think you will be requesting from that public API? Once an hour? Once a minute?

Comment: I'd suggest you take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37793338/1772245 ... it's NOT the cleanest example but will work. ANOTHER approach would be to have your lambda functions make a request to a random http proxy out of list you add to your code, you can find more https://hidemy.name/en/proxy-list/ or use a paid server that has servers around the world (change their IP twice a day) like http://proxymesh.com/features/

Comment: Oh, that's a great idea! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you place your Lambda functions outside of a VPC, your API will see requests coming from different hosts or sometimes the same one (Which is unpredictable since AWS reuses already  provisioned Hot Lambda functions to handle requests for the same configuration)

However if you place your Lambda functions inside a VPC in a private subnet while configuring a NAT gateway for egress traffic, your API will see them coming from the NAT gateway IP address.

Depending on your rquirement you can use either the approaches where mostly the second option is needed for security purposes to whitelist IPs for ingress traffic to the API.

Comment: Well, my problem is that even though it's public API it doesn't state what request rate would be considered throttling. It has happened already when I used single server polling it, so my IP got blocked. And another weird part is that this API is behind the CloudFront, so will it block an IP from its own subnet if lambda happens to be reusing the same instance over and over? I haven't tested lambda with actual trigger and in parallel, but when I click `test` in AWS console, it seems to reuse the same IP :(

Comment: Is this is a API you manage? If so do you have AWS WAF integrated with CloudFront for IP blocking?

Comment: No, otherwise I would knew throttling limit. Or better figured out the way to make bulk requests or something. So I have zero information about this API except that it's public (no authentication) and provided by the government according to the law on disclosing information. UPDATE: And yes, I'm pretty sure they have WAF integrated.

Comment: @IvanYouroff if you are getting blocked, **that means something**. The responsibility rests with you to comply with the restrictions or make arrangements for increased access with the entity providing the API.  Using Lambda or any other strategy to simply bypass restrictions is unethical behavior.  Whether the API is "public" is irrelevant.